# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split'). Same Error using Slice too

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, split, slice

**I am making Api name getItems. My coordinates are something like this "30.7409923,76.7803911". I am using split method here but it's say undefinded. Also used slice Method same results**

```
async function getItems() {
    var result = {};

    const details = await db.query("Some query executing");

    result.data = details.map(item => {


        const coordinates = COORDINATES[item.access_key];
        const [longitude, latitude] = coordinates.split(',');
        return {
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        }
    });
    result.success = true;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you print the `coordinates` variable to see what it is?

Comment: COORDINATES[item.access_key] its a array where I am passing value. coordinates are printing but at the end coordinates print undefined.

Comment: So there is no value for some `item.access_key`. You need to find the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should run fine unless `COORDINATES[item.access_key]` is `undefined`

```js
const coordinates = "30.7409923,76.7803911";
const [longitude, latitude] = coordinates.split(',');
console.log({
            latitude: latitude,
            longitude: longitude
        })
```